# “Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64”

Tags: xcode, macos, findersync

I'm trying to write a findersync program. i got the following error.

[image]

I found a variety of ways to solve the error but failed. Eventually, I tried to put the IpcManager.m  to my host app's "bulid phase" -> complie source,and it worked. I  am very confused. The IpcManager.m is deposited in the findersync target and is called by FinderSync.m.

Thanks for any help or pointers to the right direction.

Comment: complie source,and it worked. So what is your question ?

Comment: @Mingebag I had two targets,a extension target and a host target. the file IpcManager.m is deposited in the FinderSync extension target. But when i configured the compile source in my host target, I run it. I wonder why the configuration is in the host target